# Displaying Image on navigation bar and page xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.122203, I want to achieve to add an image that is half over navigation bar and another half in the page like this image

[image: screenshot of result]

I tried Negative margin and it only worked on UWP. Unfortunately, iOS and Android cut image.
I was thinking of creating a custom navigation bar but the thing is UWP has this bug that doesn't hide native Navigation right.

Any solution?

Thank you

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/stormlion227/SNavigation.Forms. Not sure if it will work in your case

Comment: You can use 2 images half on Navigationbar & half on page

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Please post it as an answer, thank you for your help it worked

Comment: Also, thank you @PriyankaAgrawal I made it half on NavigationBar & half on page great tip

Comment: @EliasNawfal Could you post your solution ? I tried the SNavigation to do the same widthout success

Comment: @doxsi please check my answer if you have any question I will explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up Copying [SNavigation.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/SNavigation.Forms) to my projects.
After following their documentation.

In the Page I override

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        if (BindingContext == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        SNavigationPage.SetNavContent(this, new LogoHeader()
        {
            BindingContext = BindingContext,
        });
    }
```

The LogoHeader is the intended layout to be postioned in the Navigation (Better use a Grid)

Visually I have one Navigation Header but technically it is cut in half.
It took a lot of time to get the perfect result because you have to remove all navigation shadows from Android and iOS but it is a reliable solution